# springSecurityFilterChain is creating exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm new to spring security. By following some article I have created a spring app with security enabled. But the problem is whenever I'm running the project it's landing into exceptions. But the same project when I'm running with commenting the **DelegatingFilterProxy** from **web.xml** it's running fine.
I have followed many question in stack and found may be I have a version issue so I changed my version to following but still facing the same issue.
**Spring Version::5.0.4**
**SpringSecurity Version::3.2.3**

Here is my files.

### Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '3.2.3.RELEASE'

    /// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '3.2.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '3.2.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-taglibs', version: '3.2.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.26'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard
    compile group: 'taglibs', name: 'standard', version: '1.1.2'
}
```

web.xml
-------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         version="2.5" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

security-beans.xml
-------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403.htm"/>

    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm"/>
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="ds"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password, status from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =? "
        />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

Controller
-------------------

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home.htm")
    public String getHome() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
```

Previously I'm using Spring **5.0.4** and Security **5.0.*** but 

stacktrace
---------------

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Security]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Security]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name springSecurityFilterChain
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1283)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more

Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)

Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)

Jun 20, 2018 2:05:38 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Security]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
```

The documentation says for spring security 4.2.0 says that the current spring security version 4.2.0 is compatible with 4.3.4 and 4.0.x.

For spring security 3.2.5 you should use spring 4.0.2
So where is the error I'm facing problem.
Additional steps taken
--------------------------
->Cleaning and building project
->Cleaning Tomcat evenif deleting and again configuring

Comment: Your web.xml seems to have last lines commented instead of just that one line, is this an accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typo error

Fix:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

to:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```